# Flink keeping all stream elements in HashMap

Tags: java, parallel-processing, apache-flink

I am trying to use HashMap in my window function of Flink job. Can all elements from all parallel operators be stored in HashMap on one operator?

```
public class SeewoUserWindowFunction implements WindowFunction<ObjectNode, LabelInfo, String, TimeWindow> {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SeewoUserWindowFunction.class);
    @Override
    public void apply(String s, TimeWindow timeWindow, Iterable<ObjectNode> iterable, Collector<LabelInfo> collector) throws Exception {
        try {
            HashMap<String, LabelInfo> result = new HashMap<>();
            iterable.forEach(e -> {
                    String key = e.get("value").get("$tid").toString() + "/" + e.get("value").get("$code").toString();
                    if (result.containsKey(key)) {
                        result.put(key, result.get(key).update(e, timeWindow.getEnd()));
                    } else {
                        result.put(key, LabelInfo.of(e, timeWindow.getEnd()));
                    }
            });
            result.values().stream().forEach(labelInfo -> collector.collect(labelInfo));
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            logger.error("parse exception!", exception);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey,
I don't think I understand Your question. I don't see any singleton in Your code.

Comment: hey, sorry for my english. what i mean is that if i set parallelism of a flink operator for n (n > 1), and i define a hashmap for count data. can this hashmap record all data, rather than only one of n parallelism opertator data. in another word, my question is how parallel operator exchange data? thank you

Answer (score 0):

In Your case every parallel operator will simply keep it's own `HashMap`, but this greatly depends on the partitioning of Your stream. There is similar question that explain communication between operators [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48537986/is-global-state-with-multiple-workers-possible-in-flink). 
If You for some reason want to have a possibility to keep all elements of the stream in `HashMap` and use `parallelism > 1`. You can call `global()` on Your data stream, which will cause all the elements of the stream to go only through one instance of the parallel operator, which will basically allow You to store all stream elements in `HashMap`, but  keep in mind that this can have terrible consequences in terms of throughput and latency.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream#windowAll` method to gather all elements into a global window.
See [this document](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/operators/windows.html).